# PyTorch Tensors - vectorized slicing with given list of end indices

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a 1D PyTorch tensor `end_index` of length L.

I want to construct a 2D PyTorch tensor `T` with L lines where
`T[i,j] = 2` when `j < end_index[i]` and `T[i,j] = 1` otherwise.

The following works:

```py
T = torch.ones([4,3], dtype=torch.long)
for element in end_index:
    T[:, :element] = 2
```

Is there a vectorizd way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct such a tensor using [broadcast semantics](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```py
# sample inputs
L, C = 4, 3
end_index = torch.tensor([0, 2, 2, 1])

# Construct tensor of shape [L, C] such that for all (i, j)
#     T[i, j] = 2 if j < end_index[i] else 1
j_range = torch.arange(C, device=end_index.device)
T = (j_range[None, :] < end_index[:, None]).long() + 1
```

which results in

```
T = 
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 1, 1]])
```